# Positive definite and continuous function

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, optimization

I'm  reading a proof with the following statement.

Let $\nabla^{2} f(x) $ be the hessian matrix and continous. Assume it is positive definite in $x'$. Now there exists an open ball around $x'$ such that $\nabla^{2} f(x) $ remains positive definite for all $x$ in this ball.

Can someone explain why this is true?

Comment: I don't think that "stress out" means what you think it means

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By [Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion), a symmetric matrix will be positive definite iff all of its leading principal minors (upper-left subdeterminants) are positive.

We note, however, that each of these leading principal minors varies *continuously* with the entries of the matrix.  That is: suppose that $A$ is a positive definite matrix. If we change the entries of $A$ by a *small enough* amount, these principal minors will remain positive.  In other words, we can find an *open ball* of matrices around $A$ that all have positive leading principal minors.

So, there is an $\epsilon > 0$ such that if $\|A - \nabla^2 f(x')\| < \epsilon$ (here $\|\cdot\|$ is a "matrix norm"), then $A$ has positive minors.

By the continuity of $\nabla^2 f$, there is a $\delta$ such that if $\|x - x'\| < \delta$, then $\|\nabla^2f(x) - \nabla^2f(x')\| < \epsilon$.  That is, if $\|x - x'\| < \delta$, then $\nabla^2f(x)$ is positive definite.  So, the ball of radius $\delta$ around $x'$ is the ball that we're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

A symmetric matrix is positive definite if and only if there is $C>0$ so that

$$v^T A v \ge C$$

for all $v$ so that $\|v\| =1$. So as the space $\{ v: \|v\| =1\}$ is the sphere which is compact, if $A$ change continuously, then the above inequality still holds (with $C$ changed $C/2$ for example).